# Georeferenced subgraphs / clusters with Graphviz

Tags: gis, graphviz

Sometimes I would like to overlay a conceptual graph on top of a map to provide additional context of where elements belong. For example, if I wanted to show social relationships between people in different countries, I might want to have the people located in their appropriate country, but with the layout within those countries being automated.

I've drawn (poorly) [a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4Q8h.jpg) to help illustrate what I'm hoping to do.

[image: poorly drawn picture :-)]

I found [this example](http://graphviz.org/Gallery/undirected/gd_1994_2007.html), but this appears to be a fake geography with clustering. What I would like is a real map where entities are contained inside their correct region, but where the entities themselves are automagically arranged.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with graphviz - the _fake_ geography map (GvMap) is probably the closest you get. Hope somebody proves me wrong ...

Comment: cant you just plot a svg layer on top of a map in something like Openlayer? I dont think graphviz is the tool for this.

Comment: Graphviz only supports rectangular clusters. If you have real geometry for each node, then the drawing only requires the tool for pretty edges.

Comment: Here is a working link for the [example](http://graphviz.org/_pages/Gallery/undirected/gd_1994_2007.html) Yours is broken. This example is from it's use case vice-versa to yours: gvmaps finds clusters and create a geographical map highlighting cluster. It generated a map out of a graph. Another example with map-like positions are: [world-dynamics](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Gallery/directed/world.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible, either, at least not in a strict sense.

However, you might try to add an invisible node in the middle of each country (use "pos" for placing and "style=plain" with no label to make it invisible), and then link the people who live there with a short edge (use "len" to constrain the length and "weight" to make it more important in the ordering). You might add more than one such node to a country, if it has a funky shape.

Comment: You might want to use "weight=0" for edges between nodes that don't belong to the same country. Or "weight=1" for nodes in different countries, "weight=2" for nodes in the same country, and "weight=3" for connecting them to their country "super-node."

Comment: Can you sketch a small weight example, for e.g. with [graphviz.it](http://graphviz.it/#/gallery/world.gv)?